# Python tkinter ttk.Notebook widget error

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, attributeerror, ttk

I have a problem with the Notebook widget with python 3.3.2

This is the code:

```
gui=Tk()
gui.title("Test")
gui.geometry()

n = ttk.Notebook(gui).grid()
f1 = ttk.Frame(n)
f2 = ttk.Frame(n)
n.add(f1, text='One')
n.add(f2, text='Two')


gui.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
mainloop()
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SergiX\Desktop\SergiX44's ModTool con sorgente 3.3\SergiX44's ModTool 1.6.4.py", line 179, in <module>
    n.add(f1, text='One')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

I don't know the reason of the error

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning the result of the `grid` function to `n`, rather than the `Notebook` widget itself.  The `grid` function always returns `None`, so `n` has a value of `None`, thus the error.

To fix this, try replacing this line

```
n = ttk.Notebook(gui).grid()
```

with these lines

```
n = ttk.Notebook(gui)
n.grid()
```